# Distinct count of multiple fields values using mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm trying to count distinct values of multiple fields By one MongoDB Aggregation query.

So here's my data:

```
{
"_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a0403f68")
"car_type": "suv",
"color": "red",
"num_doors": 4
},

{
"_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a04078df")
    "car_type": " suv ",
    "color": "blue",
    "num_doors": 4

},
{
"_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a040ld45")
    "car_type": "wagon",
    "color": "red",
    "num_doors": 4
},
{
"_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a0403dcd")
    "car_type": "suv",
    "color": "blue",
    "num_doors": 4
},
{
"_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a0403879")
    "car_type": " wagon ",
    "color": "red",
    "num_doors": 4
},
{
"_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a0405478")
    "car_type": "wagon",
    "color": "red",
    "num_doors": 4
}
```

I want a distinct count of each color by car_type:

```
"car_type": "suv"
"red":2,
"blue":2
```

iwas able to distinct and cound all colors but i couldnt distinct them by car_type

Answer (score 2):

Query

- group specific first (cartype+color), to count the same colors
- group less specific after (cartype), to get all colors/count for each `car_type`
- project to fix structure and `$arrayToObject` to make the colors keys and the the count values

*query assumes that `" wagon "` was typing mistake(the extra spaces i mean), if your collection has those problems, use `$trim` to clear the database from those.

*query is updated to include the sum also, from the comment

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70192184)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
    {"_id": {"car_type": "$car_type", "color": "$color"},
      "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
  {"$group": 
    {"_id": "$_id.car_type",
      "colors": {"$push": {"k": "$_id.color", "v": "$count"}}}},
  {"$set": {"sum": {"$sum": "$colors.v"}}},
  {"$project": 
    {"_id": 0,
      "sum": 1,
      "car_type": "$_id",
      "colors": {"$arrayToObject": ["$colors"]}}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$colors", "$$ROOT"]}}},
  {"$project": {"colors": 0}}])
```

Comment: is there any way how to add the sum of every car ive tried but every time im getting just the number of colors. 
example of what im tring to get :
{ "car_type": "suv"
"red":2,
"blue":2,
"sum":4 }

Comment: yes its easy to change it i added `{"$set": {"sum": {"$sum": "$colors.v"}}}` and i think its ok, test it also to be sure it does what you need

Comment: yes it works just fine thank you